# Problem while Transferring Json output with JOLT

Tags: json, transformation, apache-nifi, jolt

I got the following Problem:
I got an JSON input like

```
{
 "Vorname":"Vorname1 Vorname2",
 "Name":"Nachname
}
```

the output should be:

```
{ "such":"NachnameVorname1Vorname2" }
```

my JOLT specification is:

```
 [{
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
        "FullName": "=concat(@(1,Vorname),' ' ,@(1,Name))",
        "RFullName": "=concat(@(1,Name),@(1,Vorname))"
    }
}, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "PersNr": "ymitarb",
        "Austrittsdatum": "ymaust",
        "RFullName": "such",
        "FullName": "name"

    }
}, {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
        "name": "${fname}",
        "such":"$(rfname)",
        "ymitarb": "${nummer}"
    }
}]
```

and the output I get is:

```
{
    "such": "NachnameVorname1 Vorname2",
    "name": "Vorname1 Vorname2 Nachname",
    "ymitarb": ""
}
```

while it should be {"such":"NachnameVorname1Vorname2"}

my second idea was to split Vorname into Vorname_x

```
[{
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
        "FullName": "=concat(@(1,Vorname),' ' ,@(1,Name))",
        "RFullName": "=concat(@(1,Name),@(1,Vorname))"
    }
}, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
         "Vorname": {
        "* * *": {
          "$(0,1)": "Vorname_1",
          "$(0,2)": "Vorname_2",
          "$(0,3)": "Vorname_3"
        },
           "* *": {"$(0,1)": "Vorname_1",
          "$(0,2)": "Vorname_2"}


      },
        "PersNr": "ymitarb",
        "Austrittsdatum": "ymaust",
        "RFullName": "such",
        "FullName": "name"

    }
}, {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
        "name": "${fname}",
        "such":"$(rfname)",
        "ymitarb": "${nummer}"
    }
}]
```

here the output is:

```
{
    "Vorname_1": "Vorname1",
    "Vorname_2": "Vorname2",
    "such": "NachnameVorname1 Vorname2",
    "name": "Vorname1 Vorname2 Nachname",
    "ymitarb": ""
}
```

I can't manage to use the values of Vorname_1 and Vorname_2 in the concat.....
since I've not been able to find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      // split Vorname by a space
      "Vorname": {
        "* *": {
          "$(0,1)": "vorFront",
          "$(0,2)": "vorBack"
        }
      },
      // pass Name thru
      "Name": "Name"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      // concat the names now that the space is gone
      "such": "=concat(@(1,Name),@(1,vorFront),@(1,vorBack))"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The first part is working fine now , but what if "Vorname" got no whitespace? I tried [...] "*" :{"$(0,1)": "vorFront", but this dosnt work , also passing Vorname through solo dosnt work too , since if i add the field then to such i got a space in the field again

Comment: "Name": "Name",
  "Vorname": "Vorname"

 }
}, {
 "operation": "modify-default-beta",
 "spec": {

  "such": "=concat(@(1,Name),@(1,Vorname_1),@(1,Vorname_2),@(1,Vorname_3),@(1,Vorname))",
  "name": "=concat(@(1,Vorname),' ',@(1,Vorname_1),@(1,Vorname_2),@(1,Vorname_3),@(1,Name))"
 }